# Issue drawing rectangle in negative direction - Java

Tags: java, jframe, paintcomponent, jdialog

I'm having issues attempting to draw a rectangle in the negative direction from a point clicked on a screen. I have the following class that simulates a screen capture software like Gyazo:

```
class DrawSquare extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

// Components
public JDialog frame;
public Rectangle rectangle;
public BufferedImage bufferedImage;
public Point start, end;

// Variables
public String capturedImage;

public DrawSquare(JDialog frame) {

    this.frame = frame;

    // Read in crosshair image to replace mouse icon
    Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image newImage = getToolkit().getImage("components/cursor.png");
    Cursor cursor = tool.createCustomCursor(newImage, new Point (this.frame.getX(), this.frame.getY()), "img");

    this.frame.setCursor(cursor);
    this.frame.addMouseListener(this);
    this.frame.addMouseMotionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    // draw background overlay
    g2d.drawImage(bufferedImage, WIDTH, 0, this);
    if (rectangle != null) {
        //g2d.setColor(new Color(225, 225, 255, 128));
        frame.setOpacity(0.6f);
        //g2d.fill(rectangle);
        System.out.println(rectangle);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(72,119,205));
        g2d.draw(rectangle);
    }
    g2d.dispose();
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    this.end = e.getPoint();
    int width = end.x - start.x;
    int height = end.y - start.y;

    rectangle.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    this.start = e.getPoint();
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
}


@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // Get the X and Y point from the mouse pressed
    rectangle = new Rectangle(start);
    System.out.println(rectangle);
    // Repaint the screen
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
```

}

Now the reason for the issue as mentioned already, is that when I attempt to draw the rectangle box in the opposition or negative direction of a point clicked on the screen, it doesn't draw, the rectangle information looks like this during such an attempt:

`java.awt.Rectangle[x=635,y=395,width=-316,height=-194]`

However, when I drag the rectnagle in the positive direction it works as it is supposed to:

[image]

What I'd like to know is how I can fix this using negative values for width/height, or doing it another way entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should actually have 2 Points - drag start Point and current drag Point.

The rectangle is calculated:

```
x=min(dragStartPoint.x, dragCurrentPoint.x)
y=min(dragStartPoint.y, dragCurrentPoint.y)
width=abs(dragStartPoint.x - dragCurrentPoint.x)
height=abs(dragStartPoint.y - dragCurrentPoint.y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have two points as mentioned, start point and end point. Adding the solution you outlines above leads to the same result. Could you be more specific perhaps? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Increasing width and height are okay.
When they decrease, and reach 0, you need to decrease x and y.

Or otherwise seen: a rectangle is between two diagonal point topleft and bottomright. These roles change when for one coordinate (x or y) they cross.

---

Positive: you drag the bottom-right point (I guess).
Both coordinates zero: TL and BT cooincide, W and H zero.
Both coordinates negative: you leave the bottom-right point at the left-right position and drag the top-left point of the rectangle, W and H increasing from 0.

The easiest is:

- Keep the mouse-down point `from`
- Trag the mouse-drag point `to`

Calculate the rectangle between them:

```
Point min = new Point(Math.min(from.x, to.x), Math.min(from.y, to.y));
Point max = new Point(Math.max(from.x, to.x), Math.max(from.y, to.y));
```

Then the rectangle is calculated easily.

Comment: When you say decrease x and y, by what margin? By the current W*H drawn?

Comment: I clarified in the answer; @StanislavL offers the best answer till now.